# Powershell not copying files and not throwing exception

Tags: powershell

I am not understanding what is happening.

I am attempting to copy and paste dll's from one directory and another.

```
gci -path $FromPath -Include ("*.dll", "*.pdp") | ? {$_.Name -match "appMaskA|appMaskB|appMaskC"} | foreach{Copy-item $_.Fullname -destination $ToPath -force}
```

Now that command works for one function that I have it in, but not for this one...

Now, this command is moving dll's to a different server.  Not certain why it isn't working.

And if it isn't working it should throw an exception.  I did wrap that command in a try catch by the way?  Should I be catching a specific exception?

Comment: If you're just ending up with the last one, it coule be it's copying them all to the same location, and overwriting every time.

Comment: Try adding a -whatif switch to the `copy-item` and see what it says.

Comment: This same query works for another part of my script.  Only in that part of the script I am copying from one folder to another but on the same server.  This one isn't working across different servers.  I might be able to figure out what it is, but I am not getting any feedback for why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

What does your $ToPath look like? If your code is wrapped in try/catch add *-ErrorAction Stop* parameter to your copy statement as the default value is to continue so the catch block will never be executed.

`gci -path $FromPath -Include ("*.dll", "*.pdp") | ? {$_.Name -match "appMaskA|appMaskB|appMaskC"} | foreach{Copy-item $_.Fullname -destination $ToPath -force -ErrorAction Stop}`

Answer (score 0):

Does this need to be Powershell or can you use XCOPY via a BASH/CLI script. Using XCOPY you can access C Drive by doing

> SERVER.DOMAIN.LOCAL/c$/path/to/dll

Comment: Well, the rest of the script is in powershell.  Parden my ignorance, but is a XCOPY a utility that needs to be installed on the machine that is performing the copy?  Can it be called from powershell?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works for you:

> gci -path $FromPath -Include *.dll,*.pdp | where {$_.Name -match "appMaskA|appMaskB|appMaskC"} | Copy-item -path $_ -destination $ToPath -force

For complicated and/or large copying jobs I would use the program robocopy. Robocopy is part of Windows. Execute this command to verify its location:

> Get-Command robocopy|select path